# Unexpected initialization return value when initialising Datatables inside an Object

Tags: jquery, datatables

I put the dataTable function initialization inside an object but I don't get the same result as when I initialize it outside the object

Initialization outside object

```
var dataTable = $('datatable').dataTable();
```

Initialization inside object

```
var aObject = {
    dataTable : null,
    initFunction : function() {
        // this.dataTable contents is not the same when I initialize dataTable outside the object
        this.dataTable = $('datatable').dataTable();
    }
}
```

Why is this?

EDIT: Also, it doesn't seem to successfully initialise the table to dataTables when done inside an object.

Comment: Looking at the source code for datatables function dataTable() doesn't return anything, so how are values returned different?

Comment: When initializing outside an object, I get the table element that I initialised(in the above example, the "datatable" element). Initializing inside an object gives me a big Object with indexes such as "context", "dataTableExt", "dataTableSettings", "jquery", etc.

Comment: Which version of datatable are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested it using following code, and the results of both *console.log* are the same. Are you sure that you're using right selector in both places (inside and outside of object) ?

```
var aObject = {
    dataTable : null,
    initFunction : function() {
        this.dataTable = $('#data').dataTable();
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        var x = $("#data").dataTable();
        aObject.initFunction();

        console.log(x);
        console.log(aObject.dataTable);
    })
```

and following html table:

```
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                one
            </td>
            <td>
                22
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I used jQuery 1.6.2 and datatables 1.8.1.

Comment: Interesting. I tried your code, using my own table name and it works. But my code still outputs different results. The correct one has an index 0 which holds the DOM element. While the problematic one doesn't have it.

Comment: Hmm, again, are you sure selectors in your code are ok? Because in your question you've used: `$('datatable')` which wouldn't select anything since *datatable* isn't a valid tag name.

Comment: I am just using 'datatable' as an example. But nevertheless I took a second look at the markup and in turned out that the selector name was the problem.